# MVVM: Loading large data records

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

As I've learned from MVVM pattern there is an ObservableCollection in every ViewModel which holds all the models. I have a ViewModel implemented like this:

```
    public class ViewModel {

        public void LoadData() {
            Items = new ObservableCollection(_logic.Select());
            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Let's say `_logic.Select()` returns a `List<>` of all the records in the table. Now what if the data is large? What if I have thousands or maybe hundred thousands of records in the table? Should I load them all in the `ObservableCollection`? It takes a lot of time for them to be loaded.

Comment: Ever thought about using server side paging?

Comment: Actually I'm new to this stuff. Maybe I should learn about server side paging. is there any good resource about it? I'm going to google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't load all the data from the Database, load only what you need.
Think about how badly it would hurt your performance to load 1000 registries if you only need one:

You need to query the DB. Use the server to create and execute the query and keep all data somewhere, usually in memory.
Then send it to the client.
The client will also need to keep the data somewhere.

As said before, you can use server side paging AND/OR filtering.

The logic is simple, on your server you probably have a "return MyEntity;" or some method like that.

Instead of doing it, why not implement the "Take" extension method provided by Linq.

Edit:

Found this example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/17/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-8-wcf-based-data-source.aspx

That post covers more than paging, but pay special attention to:

```
public IEnumerable<SuperEmployee> GetSuperEmployees(int page)
{
    using (var context = new NORTHWNDEntities()) 
    {    
        var q = context.SuperEmployeeSet.OrderBy(emp=>emp.EmployeeID).Skip(page * PageSize).Take(PageSize);    
        return q.ToList(); 
   }
}
```

Check that qhe value of "q" uses the Skip and Take method to go to a specific item and from there, take an X amount of them.

Finally, sorting is really similar to the code above, but more complex. You can use the Where method from Linq to implement it.

Comment: If I should only load the data I need, what is the ObservableCollection good for? Let's say I have a registration form which shows only one person information at a time. Are you saying that I don't need any ObservableCollection for this registration form at all?

Comment: Observable collection is basically a collection that implementes the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
It does more than that, but basically it reflects any change on the collection itself on the UI without the need of much code from your part.
If you are only using one entity, then the form should have an instance of that specific object and all the controls binded to it's properties. @user3530012

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually I have a thousand of entities in database but at a certain time I only edit one of them and I'm not going to show a list of entities. Now I need to know ifI should have an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel in such a scenario or not?

Comment: In that case, don't use an ObservableCollection on the ViewModel os the form. Instead of that, use a property of the entity type you are actually using.

Only use collections in places you need several instances at the same time (grids, combo boxes, etc).